# Any downsides to an API endpoint returning without awaiting promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

To allow an express endpoint to return more quickly to the caller, is it reasonable to invoke an async task, but not await it before returning if the caller does not need a confirmation?

This obviously limits the error handling and retry options if the async task fails, but assuming you don’t care about that, it does allow for express API calls to complete more quickly (assuming awaiting the async task is not semantically meaningful for the API call)

How would this approach compare to other web background job approaches that are invoked via an API request?

Comment: What are "other web background job approaches"?  I don't understand that part of the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 meaning, any task that gets invoked / kicked off by receiving an API request, but who's response is not needed for the API call to return. One example, mentioned below is to add such a request to a queue and allow another process to pick it up and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly appropriate sometimes and not appropriate at other times.  It really depends upon the specific API operation, the expectations of the client, the likely use by the client and how the API is documented.

A core database operation, for example, would never do that because obviously the client usually needs to know whether the database operation was successful or not.

But, an advertising-related API that is just collecting tracking data and storing it away for later use probably has a client that is just going to ignore any return from the API call anyway and the whole thing may scale better if the HTTP connection can get shut-down as soon as possible (without waiting for some storage commit to finish).  In addition, if some of this kind of data is lost when some unusual circumstance happens, it's no big deal and the client wouldn't be doing anything differently anyway.  So, if you've determined that the client doesn't need a final status on the operation and there are scale or performance benefits to ending the request before the async operation is done, then it can be perfectly appropriate.

In another example, imagine you have a write queue where you queue up N log items in memory to write to disk before you actually write them all to disk because that improves scalability and performance of your disk I/O significantly.  In that case, the final write to disk doesn't happen until some future request by some other client when the queue hits a certain size that triggers the actual physical write.  It would be a significant penalty to the host API server (and perhaps even to the client) to wait until the final write occurs in order to return a successful API response.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of ok, but as you mentioned it has some drawbacks with regards to retrying and monitoring and synchronizing calls.

What you probably should do is push a message into a queue and have a background worker do the processing. Save a record to a database which represents the state of the operation, then queue a message to the queue. You can monitor the progress of that work by looking at the state of the record you just saved, have the worker update it.